# cannot find keytool on a mac

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, keystore, macos, keytool

I am trying to find my keytool so that I can make keys to sign my app and to register for the google maps api

I'm beginning to think that I don't actually have it on my machine

If anyone could help point me in the right direction that would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse under Mac OS X you just need to
Select `File` -> `Export` -> select `Android` -> `Export Android Application` -> click `next` -> select your project -> click `next` -> here you just chose `Create new keystore`

Comment: Actually this has only solved my issue in part. I now need to find my MD5 fingerprint, The guide on the android developers site says that I need to execute this line:     $ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore     but there is now ".keystore" file in the folder that I specified when creating the keystore by your method, does this file get created in another folder?

Answer (score 32):

To answer the original question, on my Mac, keytool is found at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`.

You can locate the Java home directory using the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command line tool on Mac OS X 10.5 or later.

Comment: Important to note that [if you do not have Java installed you will get the following output `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3879451)

Answer (score 8):

The actual tool should be installed all ready, as to my knowledge it ships with the MAC. You then have to create the .keystore file http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/keytool/ shows how to do it

Answer (score 7):

If you already have android studio installed, then `keytool` is located at

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
```

example to generate sha1 and sha256 using keytool

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my_keystone -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
2. `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk my_keystone`
3. `/Users/developer/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk nameapp.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use your keytool command in Android Studio Terminal for Mac with a random password

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

you will get -

ga0RGNYHvrrrrrrMMPWQWAPGJ8=