# Signing Android app on Mac for Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, macos

I used to sign my apps on PC with keytool, and get the hashcode that is used in FB app.

Now, I've switched to Mac, and I have to sign my app again.

I've followed the procedure explained for mac [cannot find keytool on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292832/cannot-find-keytool-on-a-mac)

I've managed to generate signed .APK, but I do not understand where to find Android Key Hash of my app on Mac?

Can anyone point me to right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Mac user so won't be able to give you a solution specifically for a Mac, but I can give you something better and simpler.

I have posted a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283088/450534. The second solution works regardless to the platform.

Give this a try. This is the exact same from the answer linked above.

I always found the simplest thing to do was, *let the Facebook SDK tell you what your Hash Key is*. This is by far more simpler and shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

*Step 1:*
In your Facebook SDK, locate the *Util.java* class. In that, change this:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;
```

to:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;
```

*Step 2:*
Create a **new** Signed APK, transfer to your device and install. If it is already installed, naturally, it will prompt.

*Step 3:* 
With your DDMS (Logcat) running and your device connected to the computer, run the application and keep looking for a *key mismatch* warning. That warning has the **actual** Hash Key. Copy that key, go to your Facebook Developer page and add the new key to the list.

You might also want to go through the comments from this answer of mine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516629/450534. In the third comment, the OP has posted the response in `Logcat`.

EDIT: The official Facebook [Getting Started - Step 4](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) pages provides this command for generating a Key Hash on a Mac:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: Hey, 

Yeah this trick with warning is nice, but actually there is keytool, the key to get there is to open Terminal and browse to /users/.android  And run in there, as there is debug key. At that point you get the hash key on the screen. Tnx for this anyway! :)

Comment: @girly: Glad to have been of help. I edited my answer with a link to the FB Docs. Perhaps, that may give you a way to generate the Key Hash. But I always found this a nifty way of getting a foolproof Key Hash. Kinda like, out of the horses mouth. ;-)